# SVG line element not rendering until I hover mouse over

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

[image]

```
  <svg class="lineSVG" width="125" height="48">
      <line class="line" [attr.x1]="lineStart" [attr.x2]="lineStart" y1="14" y2="10" stroke="black" />
      <line class="line" [attr.x1]="lineStart" [attr.x2]="lineEnd" y1="12" y2="12" fill="black" stroke="black" />
      <line class="line" [attr.x1]="lineEnd" [attr.x2]="lineEnd" y1="14" y2="10" stroke="black" />
      <circle style="stroke-width: 4px;" [attr.cx]="(ratingvalue * 24) - 12" cy="12" r="5" fill="none" stroke="green" />
  </svg>
```

I have no hover styling on the lines, and the circle element renders on load properly. I'm completely out of ideas why the lines dont display correctly until I pass my mouse over them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone else comes across this issue, I just called detectChanges on ChangeDetectorRef and the lines render properly on load

```
    public ngOnInit() {this.cdRef.detectChanges();}
```